# Why there is file not found error is displaying on codeigniter project

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My .htaccess file contains following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>**
```

My config.php has following lines:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Shifas/Codeigniter/CodeIgniter-2.2.6';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Default controller is Stud_controller

Answer (score 1):

The value you provide to `$config['base_url']` must have a trailing slash.
Try

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Shifas/Codeigniter/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/';
```

Comment: Is there anything to change on wamp??

Comment: Actually Iam new to php

Comment: It is very possible that you need to change the WAMP setup. Typically `localhost` is mapped to a directory. If the mapping is correct then `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';` might be all you need.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change the wamp setup?

Comment: Sorry, it has been too many years since I messed with WAMP and I don't remember. Maybe this https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/ will help

Answer (score 0):

You may have to allow mod_rewrite on apache https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

You also need a trailing slash:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Shifas/Codeigniter/CodeIgniter-2.2.6/';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```